# Why am I getting "Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673" after doing a database-attach upgrade

Tags: 2010, upgrade

I have a massive MOSS content database that I'm trying to upgrade to 2010 via a database attach.  After the process is complete, I get "Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673" when I browse to the site.  Can't see anything obvious in the logs.

Comment: Could you check SQL Server Log, Event View? The account you use to do this upgration type must be have db_owner on content database that you want to use. Please check it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#before out carefully.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error stems from the database being the wrong 'version'.  I eventually fixed it by running upgrade-spcontentdatabase from powershell.

Comment: Mark this one as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of the above error is:**

If we go to the “/_admin/FarmServer.aspx” page from the central administration and if we have multi severs farm – we can see one server status shows as “**Upgrade Blocked**” while another one shows as “**Installation Required**” as below:

I will explain what are these two status means.

[image]

**Upgrade Blocked**

The server is blocked from the upgrade. The current server is installed with latest CU and it will remain blocked until all the SP servers in the farm are installed with the same version.

**Installation Required**

The server still not yet installed with the same CU that is already installed on other servers.

If we summarize the above we will get the below:
The latest windows updates were installed in the first server where the status shows as “**Upgrade Blocked**” but in another server the same windows updates were not installed , so the status was showing as “**Installation Required**“.

**How to fix the above error?**

Now install the windows updates in all other servers in the farm where the status shows as “**Installation Required**“. Now browse all the SharePoint sites where you were getting the above highlighted error – everything will be opened fine.

**For details please refer the below article:**

[SharePoint Server Error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/sharepoint-troubleshooting/server-error-http-go-microsoft-com-fwlinklinkid177673-in-sharepoint-sites/)